# Context Menu from a Listview inside a fragment do not show up

Tags: android, listview, android-fragments, contextmenu

I tried everything the app starts but long pressing in the list view in the fragment nothing happens,
thank you for the consideration

contextmenu.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
<item android:id="@+id/edit"
    android:title="@string/add"
    app:showAsAction="never" />
<item android:id="@+id/delete"
    android:title="@string/delete"
    app:showAsAction="never" />
<item android:id="@+id/share"
    android:title="@string/share"
    app:showAsAction="never" />

</menu>
```

MainActivity

```
package ivano.android.com.ucanote;

import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;


public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    if (savedInstanceState == null) {
        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                .add(R.id.framebig, new FragmentAsList())
                .commit();
    }

}//end on Create

        @Override
        public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu (Menu menu){
            // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is `
            getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onOptionsItemSelected (MenuItem item){
            // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
            // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
            // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
            int id = item.getItemId();

            //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
            if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
                return true;
            }

            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }
    }
```

ContextMenuFloating( inside Fragment I was not able to add the two contexmenu methods so I attached another class that extends )

```
/**
 * Created by ivano on 3/26/2015.
 */
package ivano.android.com.ucanote;

import android.app.ListActivity;
import android.view.MenuInflater;

import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;


public class ContextMenuFloating extends ListActivity {
/**
 * Created by ivano on 3/26/2015.
 */


    @Override
    public void onCreateContextMenu(android.view.ContextMenu menu, View v, android.view.ContextMenu.ContextMenuInfo menuInfo) {
        super.onCreateContextMenu(menu, v, menuInfo);

        MenuInflater mi = getMenuInflater();

     mi.inflate(R.menu.context_menu, menu);



    }

    @Override
    public boolean onContextItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId())
        {
            case R.id.edit:
                return true;
            case R.id.delete:
                return true;
            case R.id.share:
                return true;
            default:
                return super.onContextItemSelected(item);
        }
    }

}
```

Fragmentaslist

```
 package ivano.android.com.ucanote;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuInflater;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;

/**
 * Created by ivano on 3/25/2015.
 */
public class FragmentAsList extends Fragment {

    private ArrayAdapter<String> mValues;
    public FragmentAsList() {
        super();
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
//        // Add this line in order for this fragment to handle menu events.
     // setHasOptionsMenu(true);


    }



    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return super.toString();
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu_fragmentaslist, menu);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
//        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
//        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
//        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
//        int id = item.getItemId();
//        if (id == R.id.action_refresh) {
//            FetchWeatherTask weatherTask = new FetchWeatherTask();
//            weatherTask.execute("94043");
//            return true;
//        }
     return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        String[] toDo = {
                "vai che vincerai - Sunny - Shakespeare",
                "dormire   - dolce dormire - anonimo",
                "vai che vincerai - Sunny - Shakespeare",
                "vai che vincerai - Sunny - Shakespeare",
                "vai che vincerai - Sunny - Shakespeare",
                "vai che vincerai - Sunny - Shakespeare",
                "vai che vincerai - Sunny - Shakespeare",
                "vai che vincerai - Sunny - Shakespeare",
                "vai che vincerai - Sunny - Shakespeare",
                "vai che vincerai - Sunny - Shakespeare"

        };
        List<String> tasks = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(toDo));


        mValues =
                new ArrayAdapter<String>(
                        getActivity(), // The current context (this activity)
                        R.layout.textview_pretty_cool, // The name of the layout ID.
                        R.id.text_row, // The ID of the textview to populate.
                        tasks);

        View hiddenList = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_as_list, container, false);

        // Get a reference to the ListView, and attach this adapter to it.
        ListView listView = (ListView) hiddenList.findViewById(R.id.list_hidden);
        registerForContextMenu(listView);
        listView.setAdapter(mValues);

        return hiddenList;


    }
}
```

Comment: uncomment setHasOptionValue(true)

Answer (score 0):

try setHasOptionsMenu(true); in Fragment

Comment: thank you but does not work also uncommenting setHasOption(true) in Fragment, i uncommented just to see what was happening, and it affect the menu on top of the bar where an item is not visible nor i can see the menu, but the ContextMenu still does not work:(